# Postfix: How to make aliases work for virtual domains?

Tags: postfix, smtp, mac-osx-server, alias

I'm trying to set up a local mailserver. I run Mac OS X Server 10.6 Snow Leopard, and it uses Postfix as server. I set the server up using the GUI and I'm doing all virtual settings via the terminal.

**The situation:** the server is on a domain, let's call it "domain.com". I have multiple virtual aliases, for now let's say "alias.com". I have a user "postmaster" on the server.

**My goal:** I'd like to setup some aliases (postmaster, root, mailer-daemon, etc.) that work for all domains/aliases without having to set it up every time I add an alias domain.

**Summary/to the point question:** how can I set up aliases that work automatically for all virtual domains?

**Current progress:** using the current configuration, I receive all messages to root@domain.com, postmaster@domain.com, etc...@domain.com. But when I send a message to root@alias.com (or postmaster@alias.com), the message is returned.

**Error message:**

```
Aug 17 23:53:54 home postfix/smtpd[11903]: connect from SERVER[IP]
Aug 17 23:53:54 home postfix/smtpd[11903]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from SERVER[IP]: 550 5.1.1 <postmaster@alias.com>: Recipient address rejected: User unknown in virtual alias table; from=<FROM> to=<postmaster@alias.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<SERVER>
Aug 17 23:53:55 home postfix/smtpd[11903]: disconnect from SERVER[IP]
```

**My configuration:**

```
bash-3.2# postconf -n
virtual_alias_domains = $virtual_alias_maps hash:/etc/postfix/virtual_domains
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual_users
```

**Contents of /etc/postfix/virtual_domains:**

```
alias.com             allow
```

**Contents of /etc/postfix/virtual_users:**

```
jonathan@alias.com    jonathan
info@alias.com        jonathan
support@alias.com     jonathan
```

**Contents of /etc/aliases:**

```
root:                 postmaster
MAILER-DAEMON:        postmaster

bin:                  root
daemon:               root
named:                root
nobody:               root
uucp:                 root
www:                  root
ftp-bugs:             root
postfix:              root

manager:              root
dumper:               root
operator:             root
abuse:                postmaster

decode:               root
```

I've googled a lot, but I can't find real solutions. I hope you guys come up with some genius plan :-)

Thanks!
Jonathan

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got [this awesome link](http://www.seaglass.com/postfix/faq.html#vrtglal) from a tweep and it worked perfectly! If you are looking for the answer, here is my solution. (You need to combine this with the /etc/aliases from my first post, this snippet is only for the virtual domain aliases.)

**Configuration**

```
virtual_alias_maps = regexp:/etc/postfix/virtual_users_global hash:/etc/postfix/virtual_users
```

**/etc/postfix/virtual_users_global**

```
# Short version:

/^(postmaster|root|MAILER-DAEMON|abuse)@/   postmaster
/^(bin|daemon|named|nobody|uucp|www|ftp-bugs|postfix|manager|dumper|operator|decode)@/  root

# Or the long version:

/^postmaster@/         postmaster
/^root@/               postmaster
/^MAILER-DAEMON@/      postmaster

/^bin@/                root
/^daemon@/             root
/^named@/              root
/^nobody@/             root
/^uucp@/               root
/^www@/                root
/^ftp-bugs@/           root
/^postfix@/            root

/^manager@/            root
/^dumper@/             root
/^operator@/           root
/^abuse@/              postmaster

/^decode@/             root
```

Comment: this won't capture also mails to external domains? i.e. if one of your users sends email to postmaster@external.com

Comment: @tictacbum yes, you are right! I have just verified on my similar setup and this catches all emails to external addresses that have the local part identical to local addresses. I fixed it by explicitely setting the complete address including virtual domain name instead of just the local part of the email address.

Comment: @CostinGușă here you can see what I've configured to add these aliases: http://serverfault.com/questions/637764/can-i-add-global-alias-in-virtual-alias-maps-but-only-for-local-domains/638247#answer-637784