# can I add global alias in virtual_alias_maps but only for local domains?

Tags: debian, postfix

I want to create a global alias for all my domains to catch all mail to addresses like `postmaster@`

I've added theses lines to `aliases.pcre`:

```
/(MAILER-DAEMON|postmaster|abuse|webmaster)@(.*)$/  me@mydomain
```

and in `main.cf`

```
virtual_alias_maps = pcre:/etc/postfix/aliases.pcre
```

but it catches mails to external domains too, i.e. redirecting to me mails sent to postmaster@external.com

Can I redirect all mail sent to theses addresses but only if domain is in `virtual_mailbox_domains`? (without writing the domain names in `aliases.pcre`

*** update ***

users, domains, alias.. are stored in a database, using postfixadmin to manage it.

alias tables looks like this:

```
mysql> describe alias;
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default             | Extra |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
| address  | varchar(255) | NO   | PRI | NULL                |       |
| goto     | text         | NO   |     | NULL                |       |
| domain   | varchar(255) | NO   | MUL | NULL                |       |
| created  | datetime     | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |       |
| modified | datetime     | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |       |
| active   | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | 1                   |       |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
```

ideally it should respect alias from database if it's set, and only redirect mail for addresses without alias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As alternative, instead long query as proposed above you can split to two sql maps

```
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-aliases.cf, mysql:/etc/postfix/my-custom-query.cf
```

Both files has same parameter except the query. For `/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-aliases.cf`, you can use default query from postfixadmin

```
SELECT goto FROM alias WHERE address = '%s'
```

And for `my-custom-query.cf` you have query

```
select 'me@example.com' AS goto from domain where domain='%d' AND '%u' REGEXP '^(MAILER-DAEMON|postmaster|abuse|webmaster)$' LIMIT 1;
```

**How it works**

If your first maps `mysql-virtual-aliases.cf` returns *null*, then postfix will attempt to query to second maps `my-custom-query.cf`.

**Pros:**

- If your email address match query in `mysql-virtual-aliases.cf`, then you just run one simple query.

**Cons:**

- If your email address doesn't match query in `mysql-virtual-aliases.cf`, you must run *additional* second query.

Comment: I think it does the same number of queries than mine, since it's more readable I'll accept your solution

Comment: In addition with this solution generic alias still work (@domain --> mail@domain)

Answer (score 2):

Finally this is what I configured

in `/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-aliases.cf`:

```
hosts = localhost
user = postfix
password = mypass
dbname = postfix

query = SELECT goto FROM alias WHERE address = '%s'
```

in `/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-aliases-postmaster.cf`:

```
hosts = localhost
user = postfix
password = mypass
dbname = postfix

query = SELECT 'me@mydomain' AS goto FROM domain WHERE
        domain='%d' AND active = '1' AND
        '%u' REGEXP '^(MAILER-DAEMON|postmaster|abuse|webmaster)$' LIMIT 1
```

and in `main.cf`:

```
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-aliases.cf,
                     mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-aliases-postmaster.cf
```

Maybe someone knows an easier/efficent way?

Comment: What's the purpose of `alias` and `domain` in your query above? It would be useful if you post how your virtual_mailbox_domains table looks like...

Comment: If my assumption (about table structure) was right, maybe this query will works `select 'me@example.com' from domain where domain='%d' AND '%u' IN ('MAILER-DAEMON','postmaster','abuse','webmaster');`

Comment: I updated my question with `alias` table.

Comment: @masegaloeh the query should return real `goto` value for other addresses

Comment: I've fixed SQL query, now it's working, but maybe there's a better way to do this, this long query will be executed for every mail...