# Auto forward email for mail system use Postfix + Dovecot authenticate against Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, postfix

I have a mail server with postfix + dovecot lookup to Active Directory for user authenticaiton and mailbox and deliver mail to virtual mailbox (dovecot)
User authentication for IMAP/POP are working well but now I want to enable SMTP authentication with Active Directory.

I have no clue that where to start with postfix to do that, can anyone give me a hint / guide?

Thanks in advance!

----update---

Sorry, I don't know what's wrong with me.

Acttually, what I wan to ask is with kind of that setup, how do I enable auto forward email of a user to another email address when he receive new email.
Postfix use alias to forward email of user (IIRC) but with virtual user like this setup virtual_alias_maps is use for mail group (mail list) so I have no idea.
Is postfix can lookup from multi maps as specially in this case: virtual_alias_maps?

Sorry for dumb question, maybe I need rest when post it.

Comment: `Is postfix can lookup from multi maps?` **Yes**. Do you mean like [this answers](http://serverfault.com/a/638247/218590)?

Answer (score 2):

For authenticated outgoing SMTP traffic you want to use the dovecot SASL in postfix as described here: http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html#server_dovecot

I didn't quite get if your delivery to dovecot is working or not. If you currently don't receive mails from postfix in dovecot, then follow this dovecot wiki article: http://wiki2.dovecot.org/LDA/Postfix#Virtual_users

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm busy so not try this immediately. Will let you know the result.
At the moment, I can receive mail in dovecot IMAP/POP3.