# Can I use /etc/aliases for multiple domain mail server?

Tags: postfix, sendmail, aliases

I have *server1.com* and *server2.com* both pointing to the same server. I wish to make all email sending to *@server1.com* and *@server2.com* going to the same mailbox in that particular server.

I searched around in the Internet and found out I need to configure **virtual domain** for the MTA no matter it's Sendmail or Postfix.

I wonder can I just use `/etc/aliases` for such purpose ? For example:

```
info@server1.com:  info
info@server2.com:  info
```

Or I can't do like that and have to use the setup described over here : [Sendmail multi domain](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/configure-it-quick-set-up-sendmail-to-host-multiple-domains/), [Postfix multi domain](http://www.akadia.com/services/postfix_separate_mailboxes.html) ?

Comment: Take a look in http://serverfault.com/questions/171616/postfix-how-to-make-aliases-work-for-virtual-domains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### YES

For postfix you need to ensure these two parameters

```
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
mydestination = domain1.com domain2.com
```

As postfix has many similiarities with sendmail (including `/etc/aliases` support), then you can use same `/etc/aliases`. The sendmail equivalent setting for postfix-`mydestination` is putting the domains to `/etc/mail/local-host-names`. For example

```
# local-host-names - include all aliases for your machine here.
domain1.com
domain2.com
```

References:

- [Sendmail](http://www.faqs.org/docs/securing/chap22sec180.html)
- [Postfix](http://www.postfix.org/STANDARD_CONFIGURATION_README.html#local_network)

Comment: And to set the `aliases` correctly, I should just need to put one entry since `aliases` will not care what is the domain name after the '@', which mean by using `aliases`, I can only make all emails with the same name but different domain go to the same destination. [This answer](http://serverfault.com/a/738850/273982) has elaborated it quite well.

Comment: /etc/aliases does not support the example given in the original question, you cannot route info@domain1.com and info@domain2.com to two separate addresses with /etc/aliases. I just tried it and got "warning: name must be local."

Comment: to be clear re Tom's comment, I tried it too and yes, all it does is collapse all mydestination domains by lopping off the domain name to the username and mapping that against /etc/aliases: so foo@bar.com and foo@baz.com will map on alias foo: quux to quux's mailbox for both domains. You are not allowed to have an @ in the first field of /etc/aliases.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use `/etc/aliases` for virtual alias domains, so your syntax is wrong. Correct syntax is:

```
name: addr_1, addr_2, addr_3, . . .
```

Where name has to be the alias, the part *before* `@`. What's *after* the `@`depends on what is configured in `mydestination` (Postfix) or `/etc/mail/local-host-names` (Sendmail). There, you can have the list of your domain names.

Then, the `addr_1` etc. can be local usernames, local `/path/name`s, `|commands` or even `:include: /path/name`s.

If the aliases are always the same on every domain, `/etc/aliases`is just fine. If you need different destinations for `info@example.com` and `info@example.org`, you need to use virtual aliases. In Postfix it can be done with  [virtual_alias_maps](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#virtual_alias_maps).

Comment: So on whether can we use `aliases` to achieve the multi mail domain setup is, whether the destination is the same or not.

Comment: If every domain has exactly the same mailboxes, it is possible. However, if you need even one exception, use virtual alias domains instead.